# Function str_replace and url replacing ¿ how to?

Tags: php, string, csv, replace

I need to use `str_replace()` for replace text in a `.csv` file.

I have a `.csv` file of providers and in the description file I have bad url's.

For example:

```
<p><img src='../imagebank/productos/moviles/repuestos/1462407_5.jpg' alt='Herramienta' width='500' height='500' /></p>
```

I need replace the characters `../` to domain url.

For making this url:

```
http://www.tecnostar.es/imagebank/productos/moviles/repuestos/1462407_5.jpg
```

This is my code:

```
$data['description'] = str_replace('../','http://www.tecnostar.es/',trim($csv[14]));
```

The problem are in the `//` the php interpreted a "comment" code and don't works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dots `.`
Use  `preg_replace` instead:

```
$data['description'] = preg_replace('%\.\./%','http://www.tecnostar.es/',trim($csv[14]));
```

Comment: I think you are mixing `preg_replace()` with `str_replace()`

Comment: I just copied the OP code and it was wrong... tks for pointing that :)